# Selecting uncountably many random numbers from (0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If uncountably many numbers are selected uniformly at random from $(0,1)$, and put in the initially empty set S, then;

What is the probability S contains $1/\pi$?
What is the probability S contains all rationals in $(0,1)$?
What is the probability that $S=(0,1)$?

Comment: How does your selection process work?

Comment: Pick a number at random, repeat uncountably many times.

Comment: How exactly do you repeat uncountably many times?

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you mean by 'repeat uncountably many times'. Picking one number, then another, then another, and so on, can only possibly get you a countable set. If you want to proceed transfinitely then you need to have some sort of limiting process so get you past this... but it's not clear what the limiting process should be.

Comment: The question is ill-defined in a couple of ways.  Firstly, “uncountably many” is ambiguous, since there are many different uncountable cardinals.  But more seriously, even fixing some uncountable set $I$, you need to specify what $\Sigma$-algebra or probability measure you’re considering on the space of functions $I \rightarrow (0,1)$.

Comment: Take an uncountable set A, we create a function f that maps each element of A to a random number in (0,1), S is then the image of f. So for each element in A we pick a number from (0,1) and put it in S.

Comment: "Probability" also needs to be well-defined. What is the sample space? and how the probability measure is defined on that space?... oh, @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine already pointed it out.

Comment: A number of (0,1) is selected at random by tossing a coin countably many times, with the obvious mapping to its binary expansion. So the sample space for each pick would be (0,1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a natural notion of picking a number from the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ a $\kappa$ number of times where $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal number. It is the product of the probability measures.

The problem is that in the usual formulation of probability theory, not every set denotes an event that one can assign a probability too. Using the product construction alluded to abov, one can only speak of the probability of events in a class of sets known as the product $\sigma$-algebra. It turns out that none of the events you ask the probability for lies in this class of sets. So probability theory has no real answer to your question.

Comment: @Samuel That depends on your notion of being nontrivial. A set in the product $\sigma$-algebra is already generated by countably many coordinate projections. As such, it is not that exciting.

Comment: @Samuel The Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the product topology is actually a bit larger. But a similar argument applies even there, the uncountable product $\sigma$-algebra is a surprisingly useless construct.

Comment: @Michael: Not very surprising once you sit down and realize *why* $\sigma$-algebras are generated within $\omega_1$ steps...